# IntelliJ Idea Ultimate red-underlines Ruby shorthand hash literal

Tags: ruby, hash, intellij-idea, literals

Anybody know why IntelliJ Idea Ultimate doesn't like Ruby hash literals in the newer syntax? Refer to the red underlines in my screenshot from the IDE below. Syntax:

```
{key1: "value", key2: 123}
```

Really annoying as it means my entire project has a red underline all the way up the directory tree.

I have setup a *Ruby SDK* version greater than 1.9 (which is when i think the new hash literal syntax was introduced) in the *IDE preferences*, so there is no excuse!

Thanks.

[image: Screenshot from IntelliJ Ultimate]

Comment: Did you find a solution that works for you?

Comment: I didn't unfortunately! I just decided that having two different syntaxes for hashes was confusing and used a complicated regex to replace all the new-syntax cases with the rocket syntax.

Comment: I could vanish these errors by creating new ruby on rails project with IntelliJ IDEA (14.14) with Ruby Plugin (ruby-7.1.0.20150304). I moved my all previous files to this new project. I couldn't fix this error by any other solutions...

Answer (score -9, accepted):

Answer is to replace every usage of the horrible new hash syntax with the old one using a regex (not perfect yet but works ~95% of the time).

`files=gfind . -iregex '.*\(rb\|haml\)' -printf '%p\n'
for file in $files
do
    gsed -i "s/([a-z_]+):{1}\s+(('\|"'"'")\?[-a-zA-Z0-9{}:@]+('\|"'"'")\?)/:\1 => \2/g" $file
done`

Answer (score 10):

How I fixed this in Intellij 14.1:

1. File -> Project Structure
2. Delete the existing module which defaulted to Java (doesn't delete the actual files)
3. Use green + button to create a new module with same name/location, but this time associated with Ruby on Rails instead of Java (with correct SDK)
4. File -> Close Project
5. Reopen project.

Previously I tried just changing the project SDK from the default of Java to Ruby, but this didn't fix the issue.

Comment: I opened the module, that was a rails one, and set its Module SDK to ruby (had to add the Ruby SDK).

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be a bug in the Ruby plugin: http://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/457333

Anyone who doesn't feel like changing his code base, the following steps resolved the issue for me:

- Open File -> Project Structure
- Open the Project Tab
- Change the Project Language Level
- Click OK

IntelliJ now asks if you would like to reload your project. After doing so the "new" Hash Syntax is considered correct...

Edit: It doesn't really matter what you select as language level as it is only relevant for Java code, but apparently this triggers something in the code parser...

Answer (score 3):

Under OSX IntelliJ 14 I was able to fix this by closing the project and reopening it.

In fairness, I did try setting the project's "language level", but it only shows Java SDKs, which shouldn't affect my main Ruby module.

Answer (score 1):

What helped me in my case:

- Open File -> Project Structure
- Remove current using module
- Import module ( set path to your project)
- Intellij did rest for me

Answer (score 0):

[dsager's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26431451/1057157) no longer works in Intellij Idea 14. I believe they added the ability to switch language levels without having to reload (great for java development, but breaks this). It's a lame workaround, but the only way I have found now is to create a new ruby project and then move all of your existing sources into it. Something like the following:

```
PROJECT=my_project
cp -lr $PROJECT ${PROJECT}2
rm -rf ${PROJECT}2/.idea ${PROJECT}2/*.iml
```

Create new ruby project 'my_project' with appropriate SDK, then:

```
mv ${PROJECT}2 $PROJECT
```

Side note: They made Idea's 'Open' command more flexible in 14 in that you can open any directory... much like that of RubyMine. It's quite convenient for opening anything that's not a java project, but this one is annoying.

Comment: This was the ONLY solution that worked for me and I literally tried everything else that was recommended. His script didn't quite work for me though, so I did it manually